# Java reading an Excel file

Tags: java, excel

I believe i have all the jar files I need and i'm still getting an error that says Caused by:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

And forgive me, i'm still not wonderful at reading error messages.  The error suggests the issue is with the line **`"Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);"`**

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class excelReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String spreadSheetFilePath = "C:\\Users\\userExample\\Documents\\forJava.xlsx";
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(spreadSheetFilePath));

    Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
    Sheet sheetOne = book.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = sheetOne.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIter = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while(cellIter.hasNext()) {
         Cell cell = cellIter.next();

         switch (cell.getCellType()) {
         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
             System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
             break;
         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
             System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
             break;
         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
             System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
             break;
         }
         System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
     book.close();
     stream.close();
}
```

}

Error i'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:601)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:279)
at excelReader.main(excelReader.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:62)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:85)
... 10 more
```

Jar files in my Library for project:

commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-logging1-2.jar
dom4j-1.1.jar
junit-4.1.2.17.jar
poi-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-excelant-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: ... the tension rises :-) What **is** the actual trace / error message? Maybe someone here is good at reading it ...

Comment: The question area is better suited for tracebacks. Allows more characters and lines remain lines 

Comment: You are welcome, no need to excuse. There should be an edit link close to your question. Comments have the additional problem, that you can only edit them no longer than five minutes after creation.

Comment: Could you list all the related JARs that you have? Because I've converted your project to Maven and add dependencies for `poi` and `poi-ooxml` and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I added them in the original posting of the question.

Comment: I am not using maven on eclipse so I didn't update any dependencies, I would not be surprised if i am missing a jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the StackTrace you can find that the exception is caused by :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
```

based on that I think you need the : **xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar** inside your class path, try to add this additional jar into the class path and try again ...

I suggest to manage the dependency using Maven, that will simplify everything, just switch to maven and add the following lines to your pom file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I updated the class path with that jar file, but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Update the xmlbeans-xmlpublic to 2.6.0

Comment: It was that last jar file "Update the xmlbeans-xmlpublic to 2.6.0" - aleroot.  Thank you all for your help